# get is not defined when trying to extends JSONSerializer

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I try to define my custom serializer by extending DS.JSONSerialzer.

I pick the serialize function without modifications but when i run Ember,i get this error:

> ReferenceError: get is not defined

This is my code :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    serialize: function(record, options) {
        var json = {};
        if (options && options.includeId) {
            var id = get(record, 'id');
            if (id) {
                json[get(this, 'primaryKey')] = id;
            }
        }

        record.eachAttribute(function(key, attribute) {
            this.serializeAttribute(record, json, key, attribute);
        }, this);
        record.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship) {
            if (relationship.kind === 'belongsTo') {
                this.serializeBelongsTo(record, json, relationship);
            } else if (relationship.kind === 'hasMany') {
                this.serializeHasMany(record, json, relationship);
            }
        }, this);
        return json;
    },
});
```

I didn't change any code. This is the original. Why get is suddenly undefined? It's imported in line 1 in the original file [JSONSerialiser](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.14/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L6)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have `get` defined in the scope when creating the serializer, but that doesn't extend outside of their scope into your files.

```
var get = Ember.get;
var isNone = Ember.isNone;
var map = Ember.ArrayPolyfills.map;
var merge = Ember.merge;
```

Either replace all of the `get` methods with `Ember.get` or define `get` to be `Ember.get`